# Concurrent TCP server in C that adjust its size.

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, tcp, pthreads

My aim is to create server that will be connected by many clients (but rather limited number). Clients will be running on mobile phones in LAN. 
So there can be 2 mobile phones, but can also be 10 mobile phones. But I wouldn't limit max number of phones ahead.

I think that this TCP communication with phone will be rather longer (not simple request/response but rather longer dialog between both). So thread pool seems better suited for many connection, but rather short request/response.

I think that the best will be using just simple **pthreads**. I possibly could create **1 pthread per 1 connection with mobile phone**.

But here are may doubts that there can appear to many such connections and number of pthreads will be too large. So I think about limiting number of connections for example 10 at the same time and then in order for the next mobile phone be able to connect to such server there another already connected phone must previously disconnect.

I have done something like this:

```
    int cs_fd;

    printf("Waiting for new connections on the main thread...\n");

    while(1) {
        cs_fd = accept_new_connection(ps_fd);

        if(cs_fd == FAILURE) {
            fprintf(stderr, "accept_new_connection: failed!\n");
            return FAILURE;
        } else if(cs_fd == CONTINUE) {
            continue;
        }

        // handle new connection on concurrent thread
        connection_thread(cs_fd, conn_handler);
    }
```

But this doesn't limit number of threads and connection. 
How I can do such thing?

1. limit number of child threads to MAX_NUM_OF_THREADS.
2. accept() new connection if limit not exceeded.
3. if num of child thread equal MAX_NUM_OF_THREADS wait with accepting new connection until someone else disconnects.
4. If anyone disconnects can accept new connection.
5. Client should get info that it cannot connect because there is too many connections (connected devices) and must wait.

I think than about something like this:

```
int cs_fd; 
pthread_t conn_threads[MAX_NUM_OF_THREADS]; 

printf("Waiting for new connections on the main thread...\n"); 

while(1) { 

for(int i=0; i<MAX_NUM_OF_THREADS; i++) { 
     cs_fd = accept_new_connection(ps_fd); 

     // check cs_fd is correct 
     conn_threads[i] = connection_thread(cs_fd, conn_handler); 
} 

// Here is my problem it waits until all child threads will finish
// not just one to resume accepting new connections 
for(int i=0; i<MAX_NUM_OF_THREADS; i++) { 
    pthread_join(&conn_threads[i], NULL); 
}

}
```

Now I think whether usage of some waiting/signaling couldn't help. Maybe some usage of pthread_cond_wait() when there is MAX limit reached and pthread_cond_signal() when child thread will be exiting.

In the case of client to know why it cannot connect maybe I should make separate thread with separate UDP server to request/response exchange of server STATUS codes.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason you want to spawn threads for each connection?   Why not just have a list of connections, use 'select()' to see who's sending info, and deal with that info.  If dealing with info takes a while, you can hand that off to your threads (if any are free).

That's kind of pushing the problem to further processing, but it is possible that if you keep pushing it and pushing it down to where you need it, you may not need threads at all.

Comment: btw, this is a very nice book for networking: UNIX Network Programming; W. Richard Stevens

Comment: yeah I know this concept as pseudo concurrency, I plan to implement this on several ways: 1. simple concurrency but limiting max number of threads, 2. thread pooled concurrency 3. I also plan pseudo concurrency with select(). Maybe than I will test efficiency of different solution. It's rather research project. 
Now I invented threads_manager struct which will  manage number of threads and ensure there won't be more than MAX_LIMIT. I will use conditional variable to wait if there is limit reached.